# Unit (Petabyte/Pebibyte, etc.) confusion is bug?

Tags: hadoop, units-of-measurement

The command [`hdfs dfsadmin -report`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin) outputs some lines as

```
 Configured Capacity: 28099161931345920 (24.96 PB)
```

where the first number is the amount in bytes and the parenthesis, **24.96 PB**, is the problem: [Petabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte) or [Pebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebibyte)?

24.96 = 28099161931345920/2<sup>50</sup>        and      28.1 = 28099161931345920/10<sup>15</sup>

Wikipedia cites the consensus of many sources, as NIST convention: abbreviation **PiB** for Pebibyte (2<sup>50</sup>)  and **PB** for Petabyte (10<sup>15</sup>).

So it is confuse, seems a bug on Hadoop's HDFS report... So the question is 
**Hadoop community use a different convention, or it is a bug?**

---

### NOTES

- Same bug with Terabyte/Tebibyte, etc.
- there are other conventions on Haddop... on command `hdfs dfs -df -h` it uses the letter "P" (instead "PB" or "PiB") to show the same unit.
- We are using Haddop version 2.7. Perhaps was an old bug and was fixed in newer versions (please comment if it is the case).

Comment: Despite what Wikipedia might say, if you ask me the "powers of 1024" convention for kilo-/mega-/giga-/tera-/peta- prefixes (for powers 1 through 5) is by far the most common in the real world. That said, the good thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @LMS, I agree that for us, "nerds" of this community, it is natural to use the language of the "powers of 1024", this is the [_de facto_  standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard). But today, the number of bytes is in a broader discussion about *transparency* on contracts, **fake news**, etc. the confusion is a problem. And in our Big Data organizations, the "business people" (they not understand our "natural language" but only the universal "powers of 10") that are discussing cost of Peta storages: they are using the **interface fault** as an opportunity (!).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the raw bytes is `2809...` bytes, and the number is not `28.09 PiB`, then that tells you it is not a power of 10 amount of bytes.

I don't think it is a bug. When you purchase any HDD, it may say 1 TB, but it is actually not a full Terabyte, its a tebibyte .

Comment: Hum... I can say that is an **interface fault** because the confusion make real life impact, a big  cost. It is not a joke. The difference "25 PiB - 25 PB"  is 2.8 PiB (2931336 GiB)... The cost of the error, supposing SSD of $100 dolars  per GiB, is $100*2931336= $293133 K...  Or, many hours or days to communicate, and many people checking information, etc., a big organization cost. For corrupt govern or corrupt directors, a big opportunity. For *transparency* on contracts, a big loss.

Comment: Thus why on the packaging of said HDD/SSD, it says something to the effect of "actual storage capacity may be less"

Comment: See ["consumer confusion" and lawsuits here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion)